# DebugDiag not seeing exception

Tags: c#, debugging, debugdiag

I am supporting an application team and they have an issue with their web page - the below is shown:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002E569-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.
```

I have looked around here and other sites but cannot find the culprit of the access denied object. The object itself is registered in the registry as "Microsoft Office Spreadsheet 11.0".

I have decided to take a dump of the this whilst it happens so I can see where in the code the problem is occurring and possibly track down some info from there.

I have tried debugdiag and tried loads of exception settings however when I go to the website and raise the exception of `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` it is not saving any dump.

There is no default exception in the exception list called 80070005 so I am putting it down as a .NET 4.0 app and 80070005 - this is the Hex value of access denied as appears in the error message.

Any ideas what settings I should choose for debugdiag to see the exception?

Comment: It sounds like it isn't registered on the system the page is being viewed on.

Comment: Hi - I am loading the page on the system and not remotely. I am using http:\\localhost\ to ensure it is using the local system. I will check the local host file to see if anyone messed with anything in there but it is definitely on the system.

Comment: This is an access denied error, usually associated with the browser running in protected mode or configured to not allow ActiveX components to be loaded.  DebugDiag isn't going to be any help since it is not your code that denied access.

Comment: I saw a similar thread that suggested that the com object is not configured to allow launch and access permissions for the aspnet user identity

Comment: the permission on the com object is something I will check. It is not a browser related fault per se as everyone has the problem against this one server but works fine on the load balanced pair server.